# DataCollection or Array of fields from DataCollection or Array of Objects

Tags: c#

I've got an DataCollection of Entities, which I can cast on array, so I have

```
DataCollection<Entity> entities;
```

or

```
Entity[] entities;
```

Entity consists few fields, e.g.

```
string entityName;
int entityNumber;
```

Is there a way to create solution like below?

```
DataCollection<Entity> entities   ->  DataCollection<int> entityNumbers;
Entity[] entities;                ->  int[] entityNumbers;
```

ofc I could do it by foreach like:

```
foreach (Entity entity in entities)
{
    add entity to new list/collection
}
```

But I'm looking for more elegant solution (like HashMap in Java)

I think that casting my DataCollection or Array to the list would've make the job, because there we have a solution I'm looking for:

This:

```
List<int> result = list.Select(e => e.i).ToList();
```

or:

```
List<int> result = list.ConvertAll(e => e.i);
```

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg308398(v%3Dcrm.8)) `DataCollection`?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what the reason is to cast it to a `List`, since you could just aswell iterate over an array. A `HashMap` in Java is also a totally different type object. So what are you planning to do with it?

Comment: get a sum of entityNumbers is what I really want to achive. @Bleep-Bloop

Comment: Sum of Ints? So something like `entities.Sum(e => e.entityNumber)`?

Comment: @Hyarus yeah thats what I'm looking for, but DataCollection<Entity> entities do not have Sum() avaiable.

Comment: @degath Did you add a reference to System.Linq? DataCollection<T> inhertis Collection<T> and therefor IEnumerable. Linq extends on the IEnumerable Interface. [Sum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netframework-4.0) (.NET 3.5 or higher)

Comment: Nope, I didn't and it seems like was the issue for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments you mentioned you were only looking for the `Sum` of the entitynumber fields. For that you could do:

```
using System.Linq; //at the top of your .cs file
```

and to calculate the total.

```
var total = entities.Sum(x => x.entityNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

```
public class DaCollectionOfInt<T>
{
     public int id { get; set; }
}

var result = from m in list select new DaCollectionOfInt<int>() { id = m.id };
```

OR

```
var result = list.Select(x=> new DaCollectionOfInt<int>() { id = x.id });
```